# Regex to match 2 digits, optional decimal, two digits

Tags: regex

I've spent half an hour trying to get this, maybe someone can come up with it quickly.

I need a regular expression that will match one or two digits, followed by an optional decmial point, followed by one or two digits.

For example, it should match these strings in their entirety:

> 3
>    
> 33
>    
> .3
>    
> .33
>    
> 33.3
>    
> 33.33

and NOT match anything with more than 2 digits before or after the decmial point.

Comment: Should it match the 33.33 in 133.33?

Comment: No, there is no match if there are more than two digits before or after the decmial point. I think this is where I was confusing people.

Comment: A seriously good investment if you have more questions like this would be to get RegexBuddy.  Incredible piece of software that lets you write/test regular expressions on the fly.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

*EDIT: Changed to fit other feedback.*

I understood you to mean that if there is no decimal point, then there shouldn't be two more digits.  So this should be it:

```
\d{0,2}(\.\d{1,2})?
```

That should do the trick in most implementations.  If not, you can use:

```
[0-9]?[0-9]?(\.[0-9][0-9]?)?
```

And that should work on every implementation I've seen.

Comment: This is how I would do it, except, use \d{0,2} or [0-9]{0,2} to match the given example .33

Comment: Which doesn't get .33.  Try changing the first to \d{0,2}.

Comment: You also need to anchor the expression to satisfy the "and NOT match anything with more than 2 digits before or after the decmial point." requirement.

Comment: In order to anchor it properly, I need to know whether to anchor on whitespace or beginning/end of line or whatever.  Information I don't have, so I'll leave that as an exercise for the student.

Comment: Note that this one does match 333.33 (which I think you said it should only match up to two digits, but dont know if you mentioned if it should match more than two), it also matches 33.333 (three digits in the decimal area.

Comment: note this allows blank input, as the whole number and decimal parts are both optional.

Comment: `3` matches... ?

Comment: WATCH OUT! this is not the correct answer !!! please see @jeremy-stein 's answer below.. that's why TEST, TEST & TEST, ladies (and gentleman)!

Answer (score 13):

```
(?<![\d.])(\d{1,2}|\d{0,2}\.\d{1,2})?(?![\d.])
```

Matches:

- Your examples
- 33.

Does not match:

- 333.33
- 33.333

Comment: This one may be better than the "Chosen" answer.

Comment: This absolutely correct answer, the original answer \d{0,2}(\.\d{1,2})? will not work for 123.45, as it will return 12, matching the first two digits, but this one is expecting no digit to exist before the first two digits and hence will not match 333.33

Answer (score 9):

To build on Lee's answer, you need to anchor the expression to satisfy the requirement of not having more than 2 numbers before the decimal.

If each number is a separate string, you can use the [string anchors](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html):

```
^\d{0,2}(\.\d{1,2})?$
```

If each number is within a string, you can use the [word anchors](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html):

```
\b\d{0,2}(\.\d{1,2})?\b
```

Answer (score 5):

You mentioned that you want the regex to match each of those strings, yet you previously mention that the is 1-2 digits before the decimal?

This will match 1-2 digits followed by a possible decimal, followed by another 1-2 digits but FAIL on your example of .33

```
\d{1,2}\.?\d{1,2}
```

This will match 0-2 digits followed by a possible deciaml, followed by another 1-2 digits and match on your example of .33

```
\d{0,2}\.?\d{1,2}
```

Not sure exactly which one you're looking for.

Comment: This is the closest I had, but it matches 333 and 3333

Comment: @Ahawker you forgot to escape the period.

Comment: @Ahawker, you are right. By my description, your solution was correct. I was not clear.

Answer (score 3):

you can use

let regex = new RegExp(
      `^(?=[0-9.]{1,${maxlength}}$)[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]{0,${decimal_number}})?$`
    );

where you can decide the maximum length and up to which decimal point you want to control the value

Use ES6 String interpolation to wrap the variables ${maxlength} and ${decimal_number}.

Answer (score 1):

```
^(\d{0,2}\\.)?\d{1,2}$
```

`\d{1,2}$` matches a 1-2 digit number with nothing after it (`3`, `33`, etc.), `(\d{0,2}\.)?` matches optionally a number 0-2 digits long followed by a period (`3.`, `44.`, `.`, etc.). Put them together and you've got your regex.

Answer (score 0):

```
^\d{0,2}\.?\d{1,2}$
```

Answer (score 0):

A previous answer is mostly correct, but it will also match the empty string. The following would solve this.

```
^([0-9]?[0-9](\.[0-9][0-9]?)?)|([0-9]?[0-9]?(\.[0-9][0-9]?))$
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
\d{1,2}\.?(\.\d{1,2})?
```

Answer (score 0):

Following is Very Good Regular expression for Two digits and two decimal points.

```
[RegularExpression(@"\d{0,2}(\.\d{1,2})?", ErrorMessage = "{0} must be a Decimal Number.")]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
static onlyTwoIntegersAndTwoDecimals = /^\d{0,2}(\.\d{1,2})?$/;
```

and add **Validators.max(10)** for 0 - 10

Or

```
static onlyThreeIntegersAndTwoDecimals = /^\d{0,3}(\.\d{1,2})?$/;
```

and add **Validators.max(100)** for 0 - 100

Answer (score -1):

Corrected anwser

```
\d{1,}(\.\d{1,2})
```

tested in https://regexr.com/

matches with numbers with 2 decimals or just one, or numbers without decimals.

You can change the number or decimals you want by changing the number 2

Comment: The question specifically says the the regex should not match with number with more than 2 digit and 2 decimals.

Comment: corrected anwser. sorry