# Regular Expression to match more than 1 decimal point

Tags: c#, javascript

I am trying to support the following formats:

```
11.11

01.67

30.03

11.45.23
```

But the Regex i used `"/^[+-]?([0-9]*\.?[0-9]+|[0-9]+\.?[0-9]*)([eE][+-]?[0-9]+)?$/"` supports only first 3 formats.

I need to match numbers with 1 or more decimal points like **11.12.36**

Please help me out!

Comment: Is a leading or trailing "." acceptable?  `.12` or `34.` for example.

Comment: So it looks like you actually need to match more than what you say. If you needed to match just decimals and numbers, you could just do this

`/^[\d\.]*/`

What are your actual criteria?

Comment: Regex should accept more than 1 decimal point as like "11.12.36"

Comment: But is the maximum constraint 3 decimal points? If it is `/^[+-]?\d+(\.\d+(\.\d+)?)?$/` will work. If it's more that 3 you're going to have to use a collection of matches.

Comment: Please add the constraints. Can we have leading or trailing decimal places. How many digits before a decimal place etc. Minimum and max no. of "." allowed.

Comment: Should it still also match numbers like `-1.23E+45` or are you really looking to match IP addresses?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014284/regex-to-match-2-digits-optional-decimal-two-digits

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
sPattern = @"^\d{2}\.\d{2}(\.\d{2})*$";
```

it will include all numbers

```
11.11

23.45.57

12.54.78.78
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to allow any number of digits between your decimal points and any number of decimal points including a possible starting decimal point you could try something like:

```
\.?\d+(?:\.\d+)*
```

This will allow things like .123 123.123 123.123.123.123 etc