# how to limit only two digits after decimal point using Regex Validator

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using the following REG-EX validator to validate a text box for accepting only two digits after a decimal point .

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator Display="Dynamic" ID="regexp" runat="server" ControlToValidate="regexptest" ValidationGroup="regexptest" ValidationExpression="^\d+(\.\d\d)?$">
```

But I am able to enter more than two values after decimal point.

Comment: This has already answer before in several thread. Take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/308122/simple-regular-expression-for-a-decimal-with-a-precision-of-2

Comment: @DebajitMukherjee : None is working. I tried.

Comment: You mean you cannot type more than 2 numbers after the decimal? Or the interface doesn't accept?

Comment: @7alhashmi : I want something like this "123.55". Right now in my aspx file I have applied a <asp:regularExp validator. But still I am able to enter value as " 123.55555" (more that two 5 after decimal point)

Comment: Try this out 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014284/regex-to-match-2-digits-optional-decimal-two-digits

Comment: I guess you are trying to prevent the user to enter more than two numbers after the decimal. You can do it using AJAX toolkit. Try this: http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/FilteredTextBox/FilteredTextBox.aspx

Comment: Note that either of the two current answers (MicrosoftDJ's and 7alhashmi's) will only work if the decimal separator in the current locale is the period.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator Display="Dynamic" ID="regexp" runat="server" 
     ControlToValidate="regexptest" ValidationGroup="regexptest" 
     ValidationExpression="^\d+(\.\d{1,2})?$">
```

Comment: Try this

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014284/regex-to-match-2-digits-optional-decimal-two-digits

Comment: How can do the same using ajax. that is even if the user tries to enter he is not able to enter more than 2 characters after decimal

Answer (score 6):

```
^\d+(\.\d{2})?$
```

valid Examples are - 23, 23.12
Invalid example- 23.2, 23.123

**Edit:**

Please have a look at following links to restrict the user from entering more than two numbers after decimal-

http://www.mredkj.com/tutorials/validate2.html

http://www.mredkj.com/tutorials/validate2.js

Comment: It works. But,how can I do the same using ajax. That is even if the user tries to enter he is not able to enter more than 2 characters after decimal

Comment: You can use a function in javascript or same to restrict the user to enter more than two numbers after decimal point.

Answer (score 3):

Either [@Microsoft DJ's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17419179/486504) or [@7alhashmi's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17418813/486504) should work fine *provided that the decimal separator is the period* and not some other character. This holds for US English, but other languages and locales use different separators so for a truly internationalized solution, you cannot rely on that being the case. This makes it difficult to do proper validation using only a regular expression.

Fortunately, there is another possibility: you can leverage [`decimal.TryParse()` with a culture specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ew0seb73.aspx) together with [`Math.Round()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zy06z30k.aspx). For example, if the user's culture is `fr-FR` then you could do something like:

```cs
string value = "1234,56";
NumberStyles style = NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint;
CultureInfo culture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("fr-FR"); // or whatever
decimal number;

if (!Decimal.TryParse(value, style, culture, out number))
{
    failValidate(FailReason.CannotParse); // Could not parse as a number
}
else if (number != Math.Round(number, 2))
{
    failValidate(FailReason.TooManyDecimals); // More than two decimals provided
}
else
{
    succeedValidate(); // Number was valid and has at most two decimals
}
```

Of course, this technique is only really useful on the server side (where you should be doing all the validation that you rely on anyway; **client-side validation is a convenience for the user, not something to depend upon for security or input validation**).

Using Math.Round() as above will catch the case of the user entering `12.001`, but `12.000` will be accepted since it is equal to `12.00` or for that matter `12`. Depending on your usage scenario this may or may not be acceptable.