# Check string is decimal with 2 decimal places

Tags: c#, regex

I have a textbox that a user enters a number into. I need to ensure that the number is at most 5 numbers before the decimal place and mandatory 2 digits after. The number must always have 2 digits after the decimal point. What Regex could I use to check this? (The solution is in C#)

Comment: have you looked at the regex generators online? It is something like: `[0-9]+.{2}[0-9]`

Comment: Refer this could be possible duplicate with two digits http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014284/regex-to-match-2-digits-optional-decimal-two-digits

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Something like this:

```
  String source = ...;

  if (Regex.IsMatch(source, @"^[0-9]{,5}\.[0-9]{2}$")) {
    //TODO: put relevant code here
  }
```

If you want *at least one* digit before decimal point, the pattern will be

```
  @"^[0-9]{1,5}\.[0-9]{2}$"
```

Comment: Do not forget to set this answer as accepted then :)

Answer (score 1):

Just Try this code

```
        string Value= "12345.63";
        if (Regex.IsMatch(Value, @"^[0-9]{5}\.[0-9]{2}$"))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(Value);
        }
        else
        { 
            Console.WriteLine("Not Match");
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
```