# regular expression for number and decimal points in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have checked the below link  for regular expression

[Regex to match 2 digits, optional decimal, two digits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014284/regex-to-match-2-digits-optional-decimal-two-digits)

regular expression should accept whole number or decimal points. max length should be 10 numbers before decimal and 4 digits after decimal.

tried this below code from above link (2 digit decimal point)

```
\d{0,2}(\.\d{1,2})?

var patt =new RegExp("\d{0,2}(\.\d{1,2})?")
undefined
patt.test(1)
true
patt.test(1.1)
true
patt.test(11)
true
patt.test(111.111)
true
```

for 3 digits after decimal also it is giving true value, which is invalid.

Comment: Your regex shorthand classes should be escaped with double backslashes and the current `/d{0,2}(.d{1,2})?/` expression matches an empty string, so the result is always true.

Comment: @Wiktor It might be a duplicate but not of that question. See my answer.

Comment: @jedifans: I agree I was too quick, but your answer does not seem to answer the question correctly.

Comment: I have updated to include both a fix for the given code and the requirement for 10 digits, etc.

Answer (score 9):

You have to use delimiters, to determine where your match starts and where it ends. And you say `max length should be 10 numbers before decimal and 4 digits after decimal` so your limits are incorrect too:

```
var patt = /^\d{1,10}(\.\d{1,4})?$/;
```

```js
var patt = new RegExp(/^\d{1,10}(\.\d{1,4})?$/);

console.log( patt.test(1) );                // true
console.log( patt.test(1.1) );              // true
console.log( patt.test(11.11) );            // true
console.log( patt.test(111.111) );          // true
console.log( patt.test(1111.1111) );        // true
console.log( patt.test(1111111111.1111) );  // true

console.log( patt.test(111.11111) );        // false, because to long after decimal
console.log( patt.test(11111111111.1111) ); // false, because to long before decimal
```

Or as suggested here, not using `RegExp` and instead use a literal. There could be support issues with `RegExp` in some browsers. The output is the same, so better use this solution:

```js
var patt = /^\d{1,10}(\.\d{1,4})?$/;

console.log( patt.test(1) );                // true
console.log( patt.test(1.1) );              // true
console.log( patt.test(11.11) );            // true
console.log( patt.test(111.111) );          // true
console.log( patt.test(1111.1111) );        // true
console.log( patt.test(1111111111.1111) );  // true

console.log( patt.test(111.11111) );        // false, because to long after decimal
console.log( patt.test(11111111111.1111) ); // false, because to long before decimal
```

Comment: You are making that same mistake - use a regex literal. Use `/^\d{1,10}(\.\d{1,4})?$/`

Comment: `RegExp("/^\d{1,10}(\.\d{1,4})?$/")` won't work at all.

Comment: @eisbehr thanks for your response. please provide the working fiddle. it is not working as expected.

Comment: Added example @SivaRajini

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Why would `RegExp` not work? Please tell me the problem of using it. It workes great, see my example.

Comment: It works because you removed the double quotes and turned a C string into a regex literal. Mind that `RegExp` constructor with a regex literal as first argument does not work in all browsers.

Comment: Thanks for your explaination. Didn't know that there are browsers not supporting it. Thought it is basic. @WiktorStribiżew

Comment: \ in a string escapes the next character of the string. The RegExp object never receives the backslash. \\ would be required in a string but that makes it (even more) complicated to read, so use the regex object literal to avoid it.

Answer (score 2):

The regex doesn't say the string should end with the last character, or start with the first one.
Try:

```
var patt = /^\d{1,2}(\.\d{1,2})?$/;
```

For your 10 digits before and 4 digits after requirement:

```
var patt = /^\d{1,10}(\.\d{1,4})?$/;
```

Comment: *max length should be **10** numbers before decimal and **4** digits after decimal.*

Comment: Yet that doesn't tally with the code example provided. I have updated.

Comment: var patt = new  RegExp("/^\d{1,10}(\.\d{1,4})?$/")..patt.test(1)- false..not wokring

Comment: That isn't the code I wrote, replace the whole line with new Regexp in with the code from my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just check:

```
 input < Math.pow(10,10) && input % Math.pow(10,-4) == 0
```

Answer (score -1):

here is the code that is working for me

```
 function IsValidNumericCode(number,messageDiv,msg){
 var reNumeric = /^\d*[0-9](|.\d*[0-9]|,\d*[0-9])?$/;
 var result  = reNumeric.test(number); if(!result){ messageDiv.html(msg);
 messageDiv.fadeIn(400).fadeOut(400).fadeIn(400).fadeOut(400).fadeIn(400);
 }else{ messageDiv.html('');} return result;
```